# Rules for deployment

Tags: qt

When I create a new project in Qt, at the end of the .pro file there are the following lines:

```
# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

What are those settings doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are just some default settings that QtCreator provides for deploying your app on different platforms. The first line below the comment sets the installation path (= `target.path`) for QNX systems to `/tmp/$${TARGET}/bin` where `$${TARGET}` will get replaced by your application's name.
Similarly in the next line, the installation path is set to `/opt/$${TARGET}/bin` but only for UNIX systems excluding Android (that is the `unix:!android:` expression).

The last line simply checks if the `target.path` is not empty and if so adds your target (i.e. your application or library) to the install list so that it will be installed when `make install` is called.